# How do I update view controller instead of pushing view controller when sending data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, push

**New to Objective-C** 
Right now the data sends fine but the view controller I'm sending the data to (tableView) gets pushed by the navigation controller. I don't want this to happen because the view controller I'm sending the data to (tableView) is a subview of the view controller that sends the data.

```
PAWWallPostsTableViewController *tableView = [[PAWWallPostsTableViewController alloc]init];
tableView.data = @"TESTING";
NSLog(@"%@", tableView.data);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableView animated:YES];
```

Comment: reload data of tableview

Comment: you can [yourTableView reloadData ] method is there ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply do the reloading:

```
[self.yourTableView relaodData];
```

Here is some delegates of [`UITableViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData):

```
-reloadData
-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:
-reloadSectionIndexTitles
```

See those for more info and determine what you need.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in PAWWallPostsTableViewController then its  no need to create its object again and push it . you can try reloading PAWWallPostsTableViewController data :

```
[self.tableview relaodData];
```

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on Which type of View Controller you want to Update as per the Data :

If it's **UIViewController** just put **[self.view setNeedsDisplay];**

If **UITableViewController** just put **[self.tableview reloadData];**

If **UICollectionViewController** just put **[self.collecitonview reloadData];**